# Angular: How can I check if a boolean has been updated in a service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent `MatHorizontalStepper` component that uses `subscribe` to check whether or not an `Observable` inside a service has been updated from `false` to `true`. If the observable has been changed, it automatically moves to the next step of the stepper.

However, I can't seem to get the update to change the step properly. Below are the two components I created.

**Parent Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { MatHorizontalStepper } from '@angular/material';
import 'rxjs/observable/of';

// Services
import { StepperService } from './services/stepper.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      @ViewChild('stepper') mainStepper: MatHorizontalStepper;

      constructor(
        private stepperService: StepperService
      ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Migration Service launched.');
        this.stepperService.stageOne.subscribe((result) => {
          if (result) {
            console.log('Moving to stage 2.');
            this.mainStepper.selectedIndex = 1;
          }
        });

      }

    }
```

**Service**

The service checks whenever a form inside a component has been completed, using `formComplete` to update the relevant stage.

```
import { Injectable, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatHorizontalStepper } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/observable/of';

export class StepperService {
  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;

  // A stage is either incomplete (false) or complete (true).
  stageOne: Observable<boolean> = Observable.of(false);

  // Function receives FormGroup from other component
  formComplete(recievedForm: FormGroup, recievedStepper: MatHorizontalStepper) {
    if (recievedForm.status === 'VALID') {
      switch (recievedStepper.selectedIndex) {
        case 1:
          this.stageOne = Observable.of(true);
          console.log('Stage one complete.');
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

What can I do to ensure the parent component gets the changed status of the observable inside the service?

Comment: You should switch to `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Observable`.

Comment: You're just reassinging the observable, you're not actually emitting a value. As @ChauTran suggests, try using `BehaviorSubject` and make sure you emit the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stageOne` Observable never emits anything other than `false`:

```
 Observable.of(false)
```

creates an observable that emits false when you subscribe to it, and then completes immediately.

What you're doing here:

```
this.stageOne = Observable.of(true);
```

doesn't make it emit anything. It replaces the observable by another one. The component has subscribed to the original observable, and has been unsubscribed immediately, since the original obervable completes immediately. Even if it was not unsubscribed, that wouldn't work: it subscribed to the original one, not to the new one.

To make an observable emit something when you want to, you need a Subject:

```
stageOne = new Subject<boolean>();

[...]

this.stageOne.next(true);
```

Comment: This worked great for me! Thanks for the clear, concise explanation; that really helped me understand what I did wrong initially.